# How do I make my command work on minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Minecraft plugin that does `/daytime`. The plugin gets recognized by `/pl`, but if I execute the command it does not work.

I tried modifying and moving the `plugin.xml` thinking Bukkit did not know where the main class was.

```
package domenicoplugin.domenicopluginbello;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class Domenicopluginbello extends JavaPlugin {

        @Override
        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
            if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("daytime")) {
                getServer().getWorlds().get(0).setTime(1000); // set time to morning (1000 ticks)
                sender.sendMessage("The time has been set to morning.");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-a-simple-command/) to create a command.

1. Use the class which is `extends JavaPlugin` as main class that register command and multiple others. This class should contains a `onEnable()` method which register commands.
2. Register command with `getCommand("daytime").setExecutor(new DayTimeCommand());`
3. Add it in the `plugin.yml` file like:

```yaml
commands:
   daytime:
```

4. Create the class `DayTimeCommand` that will be like:

```java
public class DayTimeCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    // This method is called, when somebody uses our command
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        getServer().getWorlds().get(0).setTime(1000); // set time to morning (1000 ticks)
        sender.sendMessage("The time has been set to morning.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS: I suggest you to change the name of package/class, and use `domenico.bello` as package, and `Bello` or `Main` as class name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `plugin.yml` instead of `plugin.xml`